# Check extensions of files in a directory and do an action for a specific file using php

Tags: php, directory, glob

I want a php script for checking extensions of files in a directory and do an action if there is a specific file.
For example: scan directory for images and videos and if the files are images do an action or the files are videos do another action (Note that directory will contain either image or video files).
I've read about glob() Function here but I don't know how to make a script that will meet my needs.Pls help me.Thanks...

Comment: Try something out, post your code, then we help you.

Comment: scandir() | opendir() | readdir() | substr() -> This are the functions you need, now start googling.